# access elements of an ajax response comes as a stirng of array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

i have requested to my server for list of posts submitted by users .But in response i get a string containing array of stdClass object.If it was actual array it wouldn't be a problem.But it comes as  a sting.Like the following:

```
   " array(
      [0]=>stdClass('title'='title of post','post_id'=4),
      [1]=>stdClass('title'='title of post','post_id'=4)
    )"
```

`typeof(response)` is giving me "string".My question is , how i can get access to individual elements from this ?
code:

```
$.ajax('../includes/ajaxpostinfo.php',{
    data:data,
    type:"POST",
    success:function(response){

        alert(typeof(response)); // it prints out "string"


        },
    error:function(response){
          alert(response);
       }
});
```

Comment: Copy your `ajaxpostinfo.php` code.

Comment: You need to use `return json_encode(responseArray);` from PHP API. Not `var_dump` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do some thing like this:

Server:

```
$array= array(
      [0]=>stdClass('title'='title of post','post_id'=4),
      [1]=>stdClass('title'='title of post','post_id'=4)
    );
echo json_encode($array);
```

Client:

```
$.ajax('../includes/ajaxpostinfo.php',{
    data:data,
    type:"POST",
    dataType : "json",//set data type
    success:function(response){

        alert(typeof(response)); 


        },
    error:function(response){
          alert(response);
       }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you add

```
dataType : "json"
```

in your ajax request

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

[JQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: The data type should be inferred from the MIME type of the response, but it should it should be added to the AJAX call too. Good advice, but don't think it will fix the issue.